# SELECT with LIMIT, OFFSET and WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

How i can do it work in postgres?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ITEM I 
 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0, ITEM_TYPE ITP 
 WHERE ITP.tp_item = I.tp_item 
   AND ORDER BY id_item
```

I suspect I would have to do a SUBSELECT, but my attempts failed :(

Comment: Your SQL is incomplete.  `AND ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like the following?

```
select *
from item i
inner join item_type itp on itp.tp_item = i.tp_item
order by id_item
offset 0
limit 10;
```

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) on `SELECT` gives an excellent overview of the syntax.